# Call or assignment expected. Getting this error while upgrading solidity version

Tags: solidity, solidity-0.8.x, compilation, compiler, solidity-0.5.x

I am not aware of the Assembly code. I copied the ERC1820 registry contract from [here](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1820#specification). This is written in `0.5.3`. When I tried to compile it with `0.8.0` it gave me this error :

[image]

I know it's because of the version change, but I am not sure what exactly do I need to change to compile it with `0.8.0`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with the registry contract, just compiled it with `^0.8.0` successfully. Try copying it again, you might have missed something in the syntax.

Comment: Yup you are right, I removed some part while removing the comments.